# ¿Cómo extraer contenido separado por delimitadores en batch?

Tags: batch

Estoy tratando de generar un script en batch (windows) donde, dentro de un documento de texto, pueda extraer información separada por delimitadores. Es decir, por cada línea en el archivo, separada por un pipeline ( | ), si mi línea empieza con 10, debo extraer los campos 3 y 4 de esa línea.

Ejemplo:
Tengo un .txt con líneas como la siguiente:

```
10|4728|1948492|A173T|17Hjdk|A1|1|56|
```

Cómo la línea empieza con un 10, yo debo obtener los campos 3 (1948492) y 4 (A173T) y desplegarlos en pantalla.

Esto lo puedo hacer, sin embargo, si tengo una línea  como la siguiente:

```
10||||4728|||1948492||A1738GHT|||17|||A1|1|56|
```

Me debería desplegar ambos campos vacíos (no se debería ver nada en pantalla ya que el campo 3 y 4 no contienen nada).

Sin embargo, toma los pipeline que están juntos como uno solo y me da salida 1948492 y A1738GHT

¿Cómo puedo evitar que más de un pipeline junto sea reconocido como uno solo?

Dónde elijo a pipeline como de limitador es en un ciclo for dentro de un campo 'delims', de la siguiente manera:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,3,4 delims=|" %%A IN ('FINDSTR /b  "10" archivo.txt) DO (...)
```

El 1 dentro de tokens es para indicar que es el primer campo que tomo como base para saber qué líneas tomar (el primer campo debe ser 10) y 3 y 4 son los Campos que debo imprimir y 'delims contiene el pipeline que es el delimitador de mis cadenas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomendaria usar powershell que es mucho mejor, se puede hacer lo que quieres con el comando

```
ForEach($chunk in select-string -Path .\archivo.txt '^10\|'){($chunk -as [string]).split('|')[0,2,3] -join "|"}
```

Comment: Te agradezco la respuesta, probé el comando pero aún así me causa conflicto. Pues si mi línea inicia con 101 me la detecta como válida.

Comment: Puedes solucionar eso facilmente aplicando una expresion regular, edito mi respuesta para que se adapte a tus necesidades

Comment: Cómo podría hacer esa expresión regular en batch. Perdona mi ignorancia, soy realmente nuevo en esto

Answer (score 0):

No existe ningún mecanismo para evitar que una secuencia de delimitadores sea procesada como un único delimitador. La solución más práctica es separar los delimitadores y entonces procesar la línea

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Generar un fichero de prueba
    > "input.txt" (
        for %%a in (
            "10|4728|1948492|A173T|17Hjdk|A1|1|56|"
            "10||||4728|||1948492||A1738GHT|||17|||A1|1|56|"
        ) do echo %%~a
    )

    rem Leer fichero de entrada
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("input.txt") do (
        rem Almacenar en una variable el contenido del registro
        set "linea=%%l"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        rem Separar las repeticiones del delimitador
        rem He usado un guion bajo, emplea lo que mejor se adapte 
        set "linea=!linea:||=|_|!"
        set "linea=!linea:||=|_|!"
        rem Separar los campos
        for /f "tokens=1,3,4 delims=|" %%a in ("!linea!") do (
            endlocal
            if "%%a"=="10" echo %%b,%%c
        )
    )
```